# Why is this question poor, how can I improve it, and what can I do in the future to prevent doing the same mistakes

Tags: discussion, specific-question, question-quality

I simply want people to tell me what I did wrong here so that I can correct my question and make it better, in addition to learn what I must not do.

[GLSL "if" statement producing segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48288027/glsl-if-statement-producing-segmentation-fault)

Comment: Look at the close reason your question is on it's way to being closed as.  Also look at the numerous comments by users explaining problems they see in your question.  Asking us what's wrong with it before you've addressed any of the problems that you've already been informed of isn't productive.

Comment: Of the people downvoting none of them specified what exactly were the reasons the question was poor. Look at the comments. I don't understand why these is a reason to be downvoted in meta, I want to improve the quality of my questions, if you feel helping me is a waste of time then don't, but why is asking help to improve my SO questions reason enough to downvote? You didn't even look at the question before commenting.

Comment: Of course people didn't tell you that they downvoted and why.  That isn't productive.  But numerous people *did* tell you that your question had problems, and how to fix them.  Asking people why your question is problematic and how to improve it *when you have already been given lots of information on how your question is problematic and how to improve it* is just wasting everyone's time.  It's not a helpful (meta) question.  When you ask a question that's not helpful, you get downvotes (on meta sites and main sites).

Comment: If you've already done everything you can to address all of the problems people have already pointed out to you (both in comments, and via close votes), and you're still getting feedback that your question is problematic, *then* it could be useful to go to meta for additional feedback.  But as is you're just asking us to repeat the comments you've already gotten, which is just wasting your time and ours.

Answer (score 11):

It's the second question today from you that claims that introducing an irrelevant line in a shader produces a segfault. Both show code examples that are so much reduced that it is completely unclear what is happening. The second question (the one discussed here) should have just been an edit to the first one. On it's own it doesn't make any sense.

For your first question, it lacked a lot of code. You were calling a function claiming that this introduces a problem without showing that function.

Attributes, varyings, uniforms are missing so we could only guess what you are actually accessing. Which glsl version are you targeting? You are not even saying what type of shader it is? Compute shader? Vertex Shader? Fragment Shader?

Then, the segmentation fault doesn't even happen inside the shader. It happens in some code that depends on the shader but you didn't show to us.

Comment: tl;dr: The minimal and complete parts of MCVE are really important.